Edit XML File In PowerShell And Save as UTF8 Without BOM
Alright, I'm trying to piecemeal instructions that I've found online, and I'm struggling...  I have an XML file that is saved as UTF8.  My objective is to create a backup (which I'm having no problem doing, edit two of the values, and save it.  Every time I save it ends up as UTF8-BOM.  I'm lost and hoping someone can help me...  Anyone able to point to what I'm obviously doing wrong?
$DateStamp = get-date -uformat "%Y_%m_%d_%H.%M.%S"

$File = "$Path\File.xml"
        
Copy-Item $File -Destination "$Path\File.xml.$DateStamp.bak"

[xml]$XMLFile = GC $File
                
$AuditEvent = $XMLFile.File.Job | Where-object Name -EQ 'AuditEvent'
$LogEvent = $XMLFile.File.Job | Where-object Name -EQ 'LogEvent'

$AuditEvent.ExpiryDuration = "$Audit"
$LogEvent.ExpiryDuration = "$Log"

$XMLFile.Save($File)

[System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings] $XmlSettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$XmlSettings.Indent = $false
$XmlSettings.Encoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($false)
[System.Xml.XmlWriter] $XmlWriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($XMLFile, $XmlSettings)
$XMLFile.Save($XmlWriter)
$XmlWriter.Dispose()


Check out this answer

@Darin, I saw that one, I guess my other concern then is that the top line changes from <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> to <?xml version="1.0"?>.  Is that going to change anything I don't want changed?

Note that your code saves the file twice. However, with the XmlWriter-based  method I can not reproduce your problem, neither in Windows PowerShell nor in PowerShell 7.

As for the encoding attribute question: as noted in the linked question, removing the encoding attribute should be safe to do, because the XML W3C Recommendation effectively mandates UTF-8 as the default in the absence of both a BOM and an encoding attribute.

@mklement0 you are right that I can't reproduce it when I remove the first save...  But something else must be wrong because none of my changes are making it to the file when I do it that way. Edit - I got it and it's working now, thanks for the help!

Glad to hear you figured it out, @ChristopherCass. In hindsight, is there something of general interest in the resolution?

@mklement0 well, I moved my edits to the line just above the save.  The way I got here was from another post I found, so in all honesty, I'm not sure what's different between mine and what the OP was doing, but it definitely works now.
